# Efficient Way to Parse XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I find it puzzling to determine the best way to parse some XML. It seems they are so many possible ways and none have really clicked with me.

My current attempt looks something like this:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(xmlText);
var name = xelement.Element("Employee").Attribute("name").Value;
```

So, this works. But it throws an exception if either the "Employee" element or the "name" attribute is missing. I don't want to throw an exception.

Exploring some [examples available online](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564), I see code like this:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\Employees.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();
Console.WriteLine("List of all Employee Names :");
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(employee.Element("Name").Value);
}
```

This would seem to suffer from the exact same issue. If the "Name" element does not exist, `Element()` returns `null` and there is an error calling the `Value` property.

I need a number of blocks like the first code snippet above. Is there a simple way to have it work and not throw an exception if some data is missing?

Comment: You could use XPATH. It has no problem with missing element which I personnally think it's a huge advantage. `/Employee/@name/text()` would select the name or null if not found. But that's not XElement nor XLinq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the combination of the explicit string conversion from `XAttribute` to `string` (which will return null if the operand is null) and the `FirstOrDefault` method:

```
var name = xelement.Elements("Employee")
                   .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("name"))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

That will be null if either there's no such element (because the sequence will be empty, and `FirstOrDefault()` will return null) or there's an element without the attribute (in which case you'll get a sequence with a null element, which `FirstOrDefault` will return).

Answer (score 3):

I often use extension methods in cases like this as they work even if the reference is null. I use a slightly modified version of the extension method's from Anders Abel's very good blog posting from early 2012 '[Null Handling with Extension Methods](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/null-handling-with-extension-methods/)':

```
public static class XElementExtension
{
    public static string GetValueOrDefault(this XAttribute attribute,
                                           string defaultValue = null)
    {
        return attribute == null ? defaultValue : attribute.Value;
    }

    public static string GetAttributeValueOrDefault(this XElement element,
                                                    string attributeName, 
                                                    string defaultValue = null)
    {
        return element == null ? defaultValue : element.Attribut(attributeName)
                                                .GetValueOrDefault(defaultValue);
    }
}
```

If you want to return 'null' if the element or attribute doesn't exist:

```
var name = xelement.Element("Employee")
                   .GetAttributeValueOrDefault("name" );
```

If you want to return a default value if the element or attribute doesn't exist:

```
var name = xelement.Element("Employee")
                    .GetAttributeValueOrDefault("name","this is the default value");
```

To use in your for loop:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\Employees.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();
Console.WriteLine("List of all Employee Names :");
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(employee.GetAttributeValueOrDefault("Name"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always use XPath:

```
string name = xelement.XPathEvaluate("string(Employee/@name)") as string;
```

This will be either the value of the attribute, or `null` if either `Employee` or `@name` do not exist.

And for the iterative example:

```
foreach (XNode item in (IEnumerable)xelement.XPathEvaluate("Employee/Name"))
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

`XPathEvaluate()` will only select valid nodes here, so you can be assured that `item` will always be non-null.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to do with the data once you've extracted it from the XML.

You would do well to look at languages that are designed for XML processing, such as XSLT and XQuery, rather than using languages like C#, which aren't (though Linq gives you something of a hybrid). Using C# or Java you're always going to have to do a lot of work to cope with the fact that XML is so flexible.

Comment: Well, I might consider your advice if all I was doing was parsing XML, but rest assured that couldn't be further from the case. Don't really understand why it depends on what I'm doing with the data. I just want to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **native XmlReader**. If your problem is reading large **XML** files instead of allowing the **XElement** to build an object representation, you can build something like **Java SAX** parser that only stream the **XML**.

**Ex:**
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c4221/Writing-XML-SAX-Parsers-in-C.htm